# Accessing latin1 mysql database from perl script using utf8

Tags: mysql, perl, character-encoding, dbi

I have a perl script using the `utf8` pragma, and for various reasons it is most practical that it does most of its operations in utf8. However, I need to access a mysql database, where all tables are in latin1. How should I do this?

A bit of 'pseudocode':

```
use utf8;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database;host=$server", $user, $pw);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
  "SELECT recipe.ingredients 
   FROM recipe
   WHERE recipe.id=?");

$sth->execute('rødgrød');
```

If I drop the `use utf8;` and save my script in latin1, this works as expected.

(I never need to INSERT into the table, just read from it, but I don't suppose that really matters.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When connecting to mysql, you should tell your script expects and provides UTF-8, so you need to tell it on connection:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database;host=$server", $user, $pw, {mysql_enable_utf8 => 1 });
```

AFAIK it is better to tell it on connection, not afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I'm a little puzzled why that can be. `perldoc DBD::mysql` says that 'This attribute determines whether DBD::mysql should assume strings stored in the database are utf8.' But this is certainly not the case. Also, should I be worried about the note 'This option is experimental and may change in future versions.'?

Comment: About being experimental: it is so already many years and too many code depend on it. There is no better ways for now. About other point: seems this variable  (mysql_enable_utf8) still tells to driver to decode strings to UTF-8 if neccessary. Did not find about it in code, because the driver part is binary.

Answer (score 1):

try setting it to something like this:

```
$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;
$dbh->do(qq{SET NAMES 'utf8';});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `utf8` pragma is due exclusively if your Perl source file is encoded in UTF-8. If, on the other hand, it is encoded in Latin1, you should *not* be using the `utf8` pragma. So is `rødgrød` composed of seven (Latin1) or nine (UTF-8) octets?

The interaction with MySQL is independent of the `utf8` setting, and soulSurfer2010 has given the right answer for that issue.

Comment: My script is in utf-8. What I meant was "if I cut away everything but the little piece above, and save that as latin1, it works". This was mostly to convince myself that the problem was with the encoding, and not something else.